# Error in linux fedora-- Permission Denied

Tags: fedora

I am getting permission denied error in linux fedora while using ./newmkapp command. The error message is -- bash: ./newmkapp: Permission denied..

Comment: this isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your file permissions with

```
ls -l
```

It should look something like this

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jcpennypincher  staff       55  5 Jul  2010 newmkapp
```

if you are not the owner you can use

```
chown username:username newmkapp
```

to change ownership, or you can make the file executable by other if you are not the owner or in the group that owns the file.

```
chmod 755 newmkapp
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier to remember than numerical permissions:

```
chmod a+x newmkapp
```

Voila ;)